# Getting recordset value without copying to sheet (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I am putting together a userform, where a user would be able to get real-time count of resolved queries from SQL Server.

Currently, I use ADODB connection to connect to SQL table and execute a Count command. I then take the value and copy it into an Admin sheet, where it is then presented in a userform.

I wonder if there is a way to present the Count command result without copying to an Admin sheet then to the userform?

**My current code**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set objmyconn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objmyrecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
        objmyrecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
        objmyconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=User;Password=Pass; Trusted_Connection=no"
        objmyconn.Open
        strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(TempStatus) FROM [DB] WHERE [TempStatus] = 'pinged'"
        Set objmyrecordset.ActiveConnection = objmyconn
        objmyrecordset.Open strSQL
        Sheets("Admin").range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (objmyrecordset)
        Me.Label1 = Sheets("Admin").range("A1").Value
        objmyconn.Close
        Set objmyconn = Nothing
        Set objmyrecordset = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any advise would be appreciated. Thanks

***EDIT****

I have amended code to copy val into a variable (test):

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Set objmyconn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set objmyrecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim strSQL As String
        Dim test as variant
            objmyrecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
            objmyconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=User;Password=Pass; Trusted_Connection=no"
            objmyconn.Open
            strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(TempStatus) FROM [DB] WHERE [TempStatus] = 'pinged'"
            Set objmyrecordset.ActiveConnection = objmyconn
            objmyrecordset.Open strSQL
            test.CopyFromRecordset (objmyrecordset)
            Me.Label1 = test.Value
            objmyconn.Close
            Set objmyconn = Nothing
            Set objmyrecordset = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: "copy" it to a variable instead?

Comment: @ashleedawg - I just tried that.. Did not work for me..

Comment: please show your updated code

Comment: See edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `"SELECT COUNT(TempStatus) FROM [DB] WHERE [TempStatus] = 'pinged'"` is still a recordset. So you have to get the value of the field of the recordset like this `objmyrecordset.fields(0).value`. This should give you the result of `COUNT`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `CopyFromRecordset` for one value

Just assign your count to an alias and use the alias fieldname from your recordset

```
strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(TempStatus) AS CountRecs FROM [DB] WHERE [TempStatus] = 'pinged'"
Set objmyrecordset.ActiveConnection = objmyconn
objmyrecordset.Open strSQL
test = objmyrecordset!CountRecs
Me.Label1 = test
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this...

```
Dim x
x = objmyrecordset.GetRows
Me.Label1 = x(0, 0)
```